# Fullcalendar: Which css selector should i target in order to display a 'loading' image while calendar is not available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

So I been trying to put a loading image while the fullcander is not displaying events.

The way i see it, there are 2 stages when the fullcalendar is not available:

1. before initializing fullcalendar
2. while fetching events

After looking at the [fullcalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading). I manages to implement the code below.

html:

```
<div id="cal">
  <h2>
    Calendar
  </h2>
  <div id="calendarLoader"></div>
  <div id='miniCalendar' class="mini-calendar"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#calendarLoader,  .calendarLoader{
      content: 'loading';
      background: url(loading.gif) no-repeat center 50%;
      min-height: 115px;
    }
```

js:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendarLoader').hide();
    $("#miniCalendar").fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: "prev",
        center: "title",
        right: "next"
      },
      buttonText: {
        prev: "Previous",
        next: "Next", 
      },
        loading: function( isLoading, view ) {
            if(isLoading) {// isLoading gives boolean value
              //show your loader here
              $('.fc-scroller').addClass('calendarLoader');
            } else {
                $('.fc-scroller').removeClass('calendarLoader');
              }
        },
    })
  });
```

While the first stage seem to work ok (before initializing fullcalendar). I cannot find a proper way to show the loading image for the second stage (while fetching events). I cant find a css selector to target in order to show the loading image. `'.fc-scroller'` or `'.fc-view'`  not really working for me.

FYI: Better selector will be one that I would not have to use `'removeClass'` or `'hide()'` in order to hide the loader

Could not find documentation for that.

Anybody knows which css fullcalnedar selector I should target and put the loading image into it?

Many Thanks

Comment: according to the docs you linked to, "loading" will trigger again (and the isLoading indicator will be false) whenever events are finished loading. So you shouldn't have any problem with the code as written - assuming your events are fetched via AJAX. You didn't mention whether that's the case or not.

Comment: yes. fetched via ajax

Comment: Can you include that code in your question please. Because if that's the case then you shouldn't have the problem you've stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="calendar">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i> Loading
</div>
```

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
loading: function (bool) {
    alert('events are being rendered'); // Add your script to show loading
},
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
    alert('all events are rendered'); // remove your loading 
}
```

});